# How to test Rails model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

Trying to test a module. It works when executed in rails console, but not when written as a test. Suppose the following:

1. MyModel

   a) has_many :my_other_model
2. MyOtherModel

   a) belongs to :my_model

Module example:

```
module MyModule
  
  def self.doit
    mine = MyModel.first
    mine.my_other_models.create!(attribute: 'Me')
  end

end
```

Now test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyModuleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "should work" do
    assert MyModule.doit
  end

end
```

Returns:

```
NoMethodError: NoMethodError: undefined method `my_other_models' for nil:NilClass
```

Now try the same thing in the console:

```
rails c

MyModule.doit
```

Works just fine. But why not as a test?

Comment: I think the issue is that you don't create a `MyModel` record before testing, so the `.first` returns nil, I'm not sure how you do that in minitest, but i think you could google to check that.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! Yes, the issue was that my test db did not have a record that was in dev db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test database is empty when you run this test, so calling `MyModel.first` is going to return `nil`, then you try to chain an unknown method to nil. What you'll probably want for your test suite is a [fixture](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures), which is just sample data. For now, you you can just create the first instance to get the test to work.

```
  test "should work" do
    MyModel.create #assuming the model is not validated
    assert MyModule.doit
  end
```

You could also refactor your module. Adding `if mine` will only try to create the other models if mine is not nil. That would get the test to pass, but negates the purpose of your test.

```
  def self.doit
    mine = MyModel.first
    mine.my_other_models.create!(attribute: 'Me') if mine
  end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Being new to rails I did not know that rails console defaults to the dev db while tests go to...the test db.